# Inform that i am Searching for a new role in another project in same company

Tags: communication, job-change, internal-transfer

I am doing my masters in a different domain than what i am working on now . Recently happened to see there is a new opportunity listed in the same organization internal transfer boars which is actually related to my course stream .
As i am a crtitical resource for my team ,Should i really inform my manager that i am applying for that role ? or should i let him find out when he actually does

PS: its an internal role change . So he will anyway get to know about this .

Comment: I wouldn't bother telling him until you give your notice. Give a proper notice (what ever you contract states, the default is usually 2 weeks). Once you have the position secured, give him the proper amount of notice and tell him then.

Comment: @SaggingRufus Notice periods typically don't apply / there are company-specific rules regarding that when it's for an internal role change.

Answer (score 1):

> Should i really inform my manager that i am applying for that role ?
>   or should i let him find out when he actually does?

You need to check the companies **policy on internal transfers**.

Anywhere I have ever worked has required *at least that you notify your manager* that your applying for another position.  In some companies you *have to actually get permission from your current manager*, which could force you to look outside your current company for other opportunities.

I would first find out what the policy and then plan your course of action appropriately.